# How to get back to HomeComponent in angular 4?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular4-router

### Router modules

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
  { 
    path: "",
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  { 
    path: "edit/:id",
  component: EditComponent
}
])
```

### Html button

```
<button [routerLink] = "">Cancel</button>
```

Above is my router module and html button. I am not able to redirect to `HomeComponent`. How to achieve it? TIA.

Comment: like <a  routerLink="/"></a>

Comment: thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/users/1225526/karthigeyan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<a routerLink="/"><button class="btn btn-default" >Cancel</button></a>`

Answer (score 3):

Shortest way:

```
<a routerLink="/">Cancel</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either do this via a function as below:

```
public goHome(): void {
    this._router.navigate(['/']);
}
```

or in the HTML

```
<button [routerLink]="['/']">Cancel</button>
```